# How to update HTML from async function?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I need to call an async function. From this function a html field should be updated. In the following short example this would be `{{typeStream | async}}`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <mark>{{typeStream | async}}</mark>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" required placeholder="0x" #address="ngForm"
        [ngClass]="classes" ngControl="address" (ngModelChange)="setAddressCssValidityClass(address)">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

My last try in the Component was using a StreamController in different ways. But I didn't find a way to update the html field `{{typeStream | async}}`. setAddressCssValidityClass() is called correctly, because setting the class in the template is working.

Here the last try for my component:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';
import 'dart:async';

@Component(
  selector: 'validate-form',
  templateUrl: 'validate_form_component.html',
  directives: [coreDirectives, formDirectives], 
  pipes: [commonPipes],
)
class ScertValidateFormComponent {

  var classes;
  StreamController<String> typeController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> typeStream;

  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
    typeStream = typeController.stream;
  }

  void setAddressCssValidityClass(NgControl control) {
    var validityClass; 
    String value = control.value;
    if(value.length == 42){
      validityClass = 'is-valid';
      callByAddress(control.value);
    }
    else{
      validityClass = 'is-invalid';
    }
    Map<String, bool> map = {validityClass: true};
    classes = map;
  }

  Future<bool> callByAddress(String address) async {    
    // Some code which needs async
    typeController.add("Hello World!"); 
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never used dart, so this is a bit alien to me. But if it is a function, shouldn't it be: <mark>{{typeStream() | async}}</mark>  ?

Comment: No, I don't think this is the case, this is a datafield, no function. Look at `[ngClass]="classes"` there I access also a datafield.

Comment: where data gets to typeController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though your stream is never getting initialized.  You need to implement `OnInit` so your `ngOnInit()` method will be called during the component lifecycle otherwise its never executed and your stream remains null.

```
class ScertValidateFormComponent implements OnInit {

  var classes;
  StreamController<String> typeController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> typeStream;

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    typeStream = typeController.stream;
  }

  ...
```

But consider this computed property pattern of getting your stream instead:

```
  StreamController<String> typeController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> get typeStream => typeController.stream;
```